# Determining index of maximum value in a list - Optimalization

Tags: python, optimization

I have written few lines of code to solve this problem, but profiler says, that it is very time-consuming. (using kernprof line-by-line profiler)
Here is the code:

```
comp = [1, 2, 3] #comp is list with always 3 elements, values 1, 2, 3 are just for illustration
m = max(comp)
max_where = [i for i, j in enumerate(comp) if j == m]
if 0 in max_where: 
    some action1
if 1 in max_where: 
    some action2
if 2 in max_where: 
    some action3
```

Profiler says that most time is consumed in max_where calculation. I have also tried to split this calculation into if-tree to avoid some unnecessary operations, but results were not satisfactory.

Please, am I doing it wrong or is it just python?

Comment: It takes approximately 50% of computing time in function that consumes in total 130 seconds and listed part of code is called 7 000 000 times over that 130 seconds period

Comment: And that is a problem... why?

Comment: Well... It is kind of hard to explain problem, but in general, I need this is calculation of something, that is similar to levenshtein distance

Comment: And again, have you actually tried using this in a situation where it has been too slow? If you haven't, there isn't a problem. Don't optimize until you have a *need* to do so.

Comment: An answer below makes I good point, I was presuming each 'some action' represent completely different blocks of code. Are they dependent on the index, all the same, or completely disparate?

Comment: some action stands for adding element to array. But for each index - 1, 2, 3 there is a difference what is added and it does not relay to the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's always three elements, why not simply do:

```
comp = [1, 2, 3] 
m = max(comp)

if comp[0] == m: 
    some action
if comp[1] == m: 
    some action
if comp[2] == m: 
    some action
```

Comment: The issue here is this quickly become spaghetti code. The increase in speed really isn't worth the decrease in maintainability. Saying *it's only three items* is fine, but these things tend to end up expanding.

Comment: Fair enough but in my case, this will probably help. I just do not understand why I have not tried this before... Maybe I was searching for more difficulties that this problem actually brings

Comment: Update: Tried this, but the calculation time did not decrease significant. So I guess, that there is not a way to make it faster.

Comment: @Jendas: In that case `max_where` is not the problem, it's just that you're calling that code so many times. Maybe you can change something in your algorithm to bring that number down, or solve it in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this many times, and if you have all the lists available at the same time, then you could [make use](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) of `numpy.argmax` to get the indices for all the lists.

Answer (score 2):

You say that this is a time-consuming operation, but I sincerely doubt this actually affects your program. Have you actually found that this is causing some problem due to slow execution in your code? If not, there is no point optimizing.

This said, there is a small optimization I can think of - which is to use a `set` rather than a `list` comprehension for `max_where`. This will make your three membership tests faster.

```
max_where = {i for i, j in enumerate(comp) if j == m}
```

That said, with only three items/checks, the construction of the set may well take more time than it saves.

In general, with a list of three items, this operation is going to take negligible amounts of time. On my system, it takes *half a microsecond* to perform this operation.

In short: **Don't bother.** Unless this is a proven bottleneck in your program that *needs* to be sped up, your current code is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try using sets. Unfortunately this really is, as you say, bottleneck. It is the most used part of my code. As I wrote above, I call it over 7 000 000 times. I will try to decrease the number of calls, but it will not do very much.

Comment: @Jendas The best solution is probably to write an extension module in C/C++/Cython or try and make a more efficient method of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon Tobias' answer, using a `for` loop:

```
comp = [1, 2, 3] 
m = max(comp)

for index in range(len(comp)):
    if comp[index] == m:
        # some action
```

Since indexing starts at 0, you *do not* need to do `len(comp) + 1`. 
I prefer using indexing in a `for` loop instead of the actual element, because it speeds things up considerably. 
Some times in a process, you may need the index of a specific element. Then, using `l.index(obj)` will waste time (even if only insignificant amounts --- for longer processes, this becomes tedious).

This also assumes that every process (for the `comp[index]`) is very similar: same process but with different variables. This wouldn't work if you have significantly different processes for each index.

However, by using `for index in range(len(l)):`, you already have the index and the item can easily be accessed with `l[index]` (along with the index, which is given by the loop).

Oddly, it seems that Tobias' implementation is faster (I thought otherwise):

```
comp = [1, 2, 3]
m = max(comp)
from timeit import timeit
def test1():
    if comp[0] == m: return m
    if comp[1] == m: return m
    if comp[2] == m: return m

def test2():
    for index in range(len(comp)):
        if comp[index] == m: return m

print 'test1:', timeit(test1, number = 1000)
print 'test2:', timeit(test2, number = 1000)
```

Returns:

```
test1: 0.00121262329299
test2: 0.00469034990534
```

My implementation may be faster for longer lists (not sure, though). However, writing the code for that is tedious (for a long list using repeated `if comp[n] == m`).

Comment: This presumes `some_action` is the same thing each time, which doesn't really make sense. If that was the case, then there is no need for this, instead you would simply do `for _ in range(comp.count(max(comp))):`

Comment: @Lattyware It assumes that they are similar things. However, you can manipulate it using the value of `comp[index]`. For example: `return comp[index] * 5`.

Comment: This is true, I presumed that wouldn't be the case given the original implementation, but the question is ambiguous. OP will have to explain further.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion and I have already fixed that. For each index there is separate action. But thank you for your answer. Maybe I would consider using xrange instead of range.

Answer (score 1):

How About this:

```
sample = [3,1,2]    
dic = {0:func_a,1:func_b,2:func_c}
x = max(sample) 
y = sample.index(x)
dic[y]
```

As mentioned and rightfully downvoted this does not work for multiple function calls.
However this does:

```
sample = [3,1,3]    
dic = {0:"func_a",1:"func_b",2:"func_c"}
max_val = max(sample) 
max_indices = [index for index, elem in enumerate(sample) if elem==max_val]
for key in max_indices:
    dic[key]
```

This is quite similar to other solutions above. I know some time passed but it wasn't right how it was. :)

Cheers!